# How to change the date format in angular Js or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, date

I am new to angularjs i am using bootstrap date picker for calculating leaves and I have to calculate number of days between 2 dates and i have to exclude holidays date(array),from number of days which i get from back end. i calculated number of days and now i have to exclude a holiday date in between 2 dates,

Example:
from date - 01-10-2015,
To date   - 05-10-2015,
No of days- 5          //but 02-10-2015 is holiday so, i have to get 4

i have taken in between dates of from and to dates as array in this format(mon 01  2015,tue 02 2015,wed 01 2015) i have to change the date format to 02-10-2015(dd-mm-yyyy) how can i do? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Just do it as

```
<p ng-bind="date | date:'MM-dd-yyyy'"></p>
```

will produce date as 12-19-2015

date is variable you will bind from controller to view.

Answer (score 1):

It has built in function for this

```
<p ng-bind="date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'"></p>
```